# Generating a text based histogram

Tags: python, dictionary, histogram

I currently have some code that will print out the frequency of each word within a file. How could I modify this to generate a histogram displaying the percentage of the values for each word.

```
from collections import Counter
data = open( 'Test.txt' ).read()  # read the file
data = ''.join( [i.upper() if i.isalpha() else ' ' for i in data] )   # remove the punctuation
c = Counter( data.split() )   # count the words
print(c)
```

Comment: There are several packages in python that allow you to create a histogram. For example bokeh, numpy or matplotlib

Comment: You could fill a dictionary with each word as a key, and the count as a value. In that way you generate a histogram in itself. numpy and matplotlib indeed offer facilities, but I think your question is how to provide input to these options, right?

Answer (score 1):

This script creates a similar dictionary liek the one you  created, instead of word count it has the percentage as a value. Hope this helps :)

```
from collections import Counter
data = open( 'test.txt' ).read()  # read the file
data = ''.join( [i.upper() if i.isalpha() else ' ' for i in data] )   # remove the punctuation
c = Counter( data.split() )   # count the words
print(c)

values_list = c.values()
word_sum = 0

for v in values_list:
    word_sum += v # get the number of words in the file

percent_dict = {}
for k, v in c.items():
    percentage = (100*v)/word_sum
    percent_dict[k] = percentage

    print(percent_dict)
```

Answer (score 0):

Naive approach using a dict comprehension and simple division:

```
c = Counter('abbccc')
s = sum(c.values())
perc = {k: v*100.0/s for k, v in c.items()}
# {'a': 16.666666666666668, 'b': 33.333333333333336, 'c': 50.0}
```